# Is there a HttpListener in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, httplistener

I am working in UWP and I can't use the `HttpListener` class from the System API. Is there a new feature in the Windows API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a new feauture in the Windows API?

Not all .NET APIs are supported in UWP app. You could check [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185501.aspx) to see all supported .NET APIs in UWP.

In your case, you should be looking at: [StreamSocketListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener#syntax) in [Windows.Networking.Sockets Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Sockets). You could use StreamSocketListener to make a similar httplistener by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It is supported with .Net Standard 2.0.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/

Answer (score 2):

It's included in .NET Standard 2.0. Scroll to the bottom of the documentation page for `HttpListener` to see what versions of .NET include it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netstandard-2.1#applies-to

.NET standard 2.0 is included in Windows build 10.0.16299. What versions of .NET Standard is included in what build of Windows can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support